# Mongodb how to get OR of two aggregated queries?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using following aggregated query to get results (let say `query1`):

```
db.fb.aggregate(
    [
     {
        $addFields : { noOfLikes : { $sum : { $map : { input : "$facebookEvents", as : "f", in : {$cond : [ { $eq : ["$$f.type" , "like"] }, 1, 0 ]} }}}}
      },
      {
        $match : {"noOfLikes" : {$gte : 2}}
      }
    ]
)
```

and another query to get some other results (let's say `query2`):

```
db.fb.aggregate(
    [
    { $match : { author : "dave" } },
    { $match : { test : "test1" } }
    ]
)
```

Is it possible to get `query1` OR `query2` using a single `aggregate` query? In other words, I want to get results that match either `query1` or `query2` using a single query. Appreciate any help

mongo version: 3.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Within a single aggregate query, you would need to run your pipeline as follows:

```
db.fb.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": { 
            "noOfLikes": { 
                "$sum" : { 
                    "$map": { 
                        "input": "$facebookEvents", 
                        "as": "f", 
                        "in": {
                            "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$$f.type" , "like"] }, 1, 0 ]
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$match" : {
            "$or": [
                { "noOfLikes" : { "$gte" : 2 } },
                { "author": "dave", "test": "test1" }
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

or using **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)** as:

```
db.fb.aggregate([
    { 
        "$redact": { 
            "$cond": [
                { 
                    "$or": [  
                        { "$gte": [ 
                            {                                   
                                "$sum" : { 
                                    "$map": { 
                                        "input": "$facebookEvents", 
                                        "as": "f", 
                                        "in": {
                                            "$cond": [
                                                { "$eq": ["$$f.type" , "like"] }, 
                                                1, 
                                                0 
                                            ]
                                        } 
                                    }
                                }
                            }, 2 ]
                        },
                        {                               
                            "$and": [ 
                                { "$eq": ["$author", "dave"] },
                                { "$eq": ["$test", "test1"] }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$facet`

```
db.fb.aggregate(
{
    $facet : {
        byLikes : [ 
            { $addFields : { noOfLikes : { $sum : { $map : { input : "$facebookEvents", as : "f", in : {$cond : [ { $eq : ["$$f.type" , "like"] }, 1, 0 ]} }}}} }, 
            { $match : {"noOfLikes" : {$gte : 2}}} 
       ],
        byAuthor : [ 
            { $match : { author : "dave" } }, 
            { $match : { test : "test1" } }     
        ]
    }
}
)
```